# How to update nested object in delta-rs

Tags: python, delta-lake, delta-rs

Given the below code, I'm able to update root-level fields as e.g. "age". But how to update fields inside `my_struct`?

The attempt with `struct("a": "1", "b": "2")` gives

> DeltaTable error: This feature is not implemented: Unsupported SQL
> json operator Colon

I also tried `named_struct`, it gives

> Generic DeltaTable error: Error during planning: Invalid function
> 'named_struct'.

I've been searching a couple of hours for docs/examples, but without luck so far.

```
import pandas as pd
from deltalake import write_deltalake, DeltaTable

df = pd.DataFrame.from_records([
     {"name": "Alice", "age": 25, "gender": "Female", "my_struct": {"a": 1, "b": 2}},
     {"name": "Bob", "age": 30, "gender": "Male", "my_struct": {"a": 3, "b": 4}}
])

write_deltalake('./db/my_table', df)

dt = DeltaTable('./db/my_table')
dt.update({"age": "42"})  # this is working
dt.update({"my_struct": 'struct("a": "1", "b": "2")'})  # not working
print(dt.to_pandas())
```

My pyproject.toml

```
[tool.poetry]
name = "delta-test"

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.10"
deltalake = "^0.12.0"
pandas = "1.5"

[build-system]
requires = ["poetry-core"]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"
```

Answer (score 1):

What is wrong is that the update accepts **[SQL instructions rather than Python-like datatypes](https://delta-io.github.io/delta-rs/python/usage.html#querying-delta-tables)**. Hence the error on the syntax `'struct("a": "1", "b": "2")'` which is not a proper SQL call.

In anticipation of the narrowed question "what a SQL-compatible struct looks like", let's emphasize that this depends on the SQL dialect used and may not be that clear. In Databricks for example we could use `named_struct('a', 1, 'b', 2)`. Here we deal with **Python bindings for [delta-rs](https://github.com/delta-io/delta-rs)**, and from the older version of the documentation

> DeltaTable.update() predicates and updates are all in string format. The predicates and expressions, are parsed into Apache Datafusion expressions.

it appears that we **may have to align to DataFusion**. In turn, according to [their docs](https://github.com/apache/arrow-datafusion/issues/2043), the syntax `struct(1,2)` should work. The provided example recognizes this syntax (progress), but still complains about data types mismatch. I **[debuged and escalated the problem to the maintainers](https://github.com/delta-io/delta-rs/issues/1903)** and we need to wait for their answer because it's up to them to document their API.